# How do I get Dev-C++ set up for 2d graphics

Tags: c++, dev-c++, bgi, winbgi

right now I am only ready to take on the most rudimentary graphics, i.e. that for engineers and scientists.  I have placed the WinBGIm files in their respective folders and added the names of the 6 files to the linker command.  However, when I compile and link I get error msgs saying the linker cannot find the stated files.  I have tried putting libbgi.a in several folders with no luck.  I am using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 in Windows 10.  What am I doing wrong or what do I need to do?

Comment: first thing wrong is to use BGI its ancient and obsolete you would be better of using something different for example OpenGL,SDL,GDI,or whatever ... if you really must go for BGI then you have to make sure your BGI emulator version is compatible with your OS (you know real BGI is MS-DOS)... the usual problem is not matching libs/compile&linker target/OS capability. They all must match the same architecture ... so if you got 32bit WinBGI set 32bit for your compiler/linker too. if 16bit then 16bit but beware on 64bit OS you can not run 16bit apps.

Comment: Finally If your compiler/linker does not see the files your paths are screwed up. First you must know what paths are screwed so the missing files (which and where) are reported by compiler or linker? If you can not resolve this you can always try to put all the lib files locally to your project matching its folder structure. Also there might be a problem with OS security settings if you placed your libs folder into restricted area your DEV does not have permitions to... did you try to run the DEV as administrator? Win10 tends to run some apps improperly otherwise...